# planning for UK visit from Germany

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, residency

As an Indian with a BlueCard to work in Germany, do need a visa to enter the UK?

Comment: Visa requirements for the UK for Indian citizens can be found here: https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GB&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C - The page doesn't list the residency as a thing that allows entry to the UK, so you need to apply for a visa. More information can be found on the website of your nearest UK embassy.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you need a visa [using a tool provided by the UK government](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).
If it doesn't ask a question, this is likely because it is not relevant to your requirement for a visa. In this case you almost certainly do require a visa.